# Regular expression with JTextField event not working?

Tags: java

I trying to avoid invalid number entry in JTextField through regular expression but when I enter the valid number its also go to consume method to consume. please guide me.

```
  private void txtphoneKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                  
   char c = evt.getKeyChar();
   String regex = "^(\\+93|0)?[7][0-9]{8}$";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(String.valueOf(c));
   if(matcher.matches() == false){
      evt.consume();   
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide valid and invalid test-cases for the regex that you are trying to write ?

Comment: `String.valueOf(c)` is a string of length 1.  It will never match that regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a KeyListener for this.

For one thing, you are trying to match a *single typed character* against the entire phone number pattern.  The fact that `evt.getKeyChar()` returns a single char should tell you that it can’t possibly match the entire phone number.

The correct way to do this is to use a subclass of JTextField, [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html), instead of a plain JTextField.

```
String regex = "^(\\+93|0)?7[0-9]{8}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter formatter =
    new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text)
        throws ParseException {
            if (text != null && !pattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
                throw new ParseException(text, 0);
            }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) {
            return Objects.toString(value, null);
        }
    };

JTextField txtphone = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

You don’t really need to restrict the keys typed;  if the user types invalid characters, the value will be rejected and the field will revert to the last good value entered.  But if you insist on restricting every typed character, you can use a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html#getDocumentFilter%28%29):

```
Pattern allowedCharactersPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9+]*");

DocumentFilter filter = new DocumentFilter() {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass bypass,
                             int position,
                             String newText,
                             AttributeSet attr)
    throws BadLocationException {
        if (allowedCharactersPattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
            super.insertString(bypass, position, newText, attr);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass bypass,
                        int position,
                        int length,
                        String newText,
                        AttributeSet attr)
    throws BadLocationException {
        if (allowedCharactersPattern.matcher(newText).matches()) {
            super.replace(bypass, position, length, newText, attr);
        }
    }
};

String regex = "^(\\+93|0)?7[0-9]{8}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter formatter =
    new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        protected DocumentFilter getDocumentFilter() {
            return filter;
        }

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text)
        throws ParseException {
            if (text != null && !pattern.matcher(text).matches()) {
                throw new ParseException(text, 0);
            }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) {
            return Objects.toString(value, null);
        }
    };

JTextField txtphone = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

You may be wondering why allowedCharactersPattern is `"[0-9+]*"` and not the full phone number pattern.  This is because one of the reasons for having a text field with a movable cursor is that the user can enter the information a little at a time, possibly out of order.  For instance, the user may type a few digits, then use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the beginning and type “+937”.  It’s best not to enforce a pattern until the user has finished editing.  The `stringToValue` method still enforces the overall pattern.

Comment: You helped me right when I needed help most, thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

You pattern matches a `(12/10)` length string but you `matcher` string is of a one length string because in your case `String.valueOf(c)` will return a string of length one. That is the reason why whatever will be your input, `matcher.matches()` will always return `false`.

You should be matching the pattern against a string like `+93775241650` or `0775241650`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\+93|0)?[7][0-9]{8}$");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("+93775241650");

if(matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
 } else {
     System.out.println("not found");
 }
}
```

Comment: you should have this logic of pattern matching in an event where you get the whole string that user have typed and get the `String` that you typed and match the regex against it. I don't think `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` is the write place for this logic